# How can I replace only specific newline's in my text file?

Tags: regex, file, text, notepad++, newline

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
#EXTINF:0,ABC family USA 
abc.com

#EXTINF:0,ABC HD USA
abc.com/usa

#EXTINF:0,AMC USA
amc.com/usa

#EXTINF:0,BLOMBERG USA 
 blomberg.com/usa
```

However I want the header and the link to be replaced to look like this:

```
#EXTINF:0,ABC family USA[]abc.com 

#EXTINF:0,ABC HD USA[]abc.com/usa
```

This way I could easily use this file and  turn the contents into an array. 
However I don't want every new line to contain two brackets. I only want the header and link to be combined and have a bracket in between them. I am not sure how to accomplish this through notepad++ ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is header always going to end with `USA` ?

Comment: @apgp88 Sorry, I just took a random sample from my file, but no the header can end with any letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text file is totally consistent (only contains lines like the original excerpt above, no trailing whitespace) you can use this regex to find line break characters occurring after and octothorpes:

```
\n(?!(^[#\s]))
```

and replace with:

```
[]
```

Results look like this:

```
#EXTINF:0,ABC family USA[]abc.com

#EXTINF:0,ABC HD USA[]abc.com/usa

#EXTINF:0,AMC USA[]amc.com/usa

#EXTINF:0,BLOMBERG USA[]blomberg.com/usa
```

**Tested in Sublime Text 3 - Both ST and NP++ use Perl Regex, but there are slight variations so this might not work for you.**

If it doesn't work in NP++, you can grab a copy of ST3 [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).